# Why is a set of p-functions added to the minimum basis sets of Li and Be?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, basis-set

*The minimum basis set* consists of the smallest number of functions necessary to contain the electrons of the neutral system. In the book *Introduction to Computational Chemistry*, Second Edition, by Frank Jensen, it is stated that "a set of *p*-functions" usually is added to the minimum basis sets of Li and Be atoms, despite them containing 3 and 4 electrons respectively and thus would require 2 *s*-functions. I can not, however, understand why.

Comment: A minimal basis includes a single basis function for each orbital assumed to be relevant to the atom (or molecules that include that atom), which are usually those in the same shell. Think about Be; you might be able to describe a lone Be atom with just the 1s and 2s orbital, but you would describe bonding very poorly without including 2p orbitals.

Answer (score 2):

By your definition, any minimal basis set would only include as many orbitals (including spin state) as there are electrons. This implies that each atom would be described as a single determinant and therefore the entire system would be described by a single determinant. Without unoccupied orbitals, there is no binding. Hence, a minimum basis set has to fulfill a few more constraints. A common requirement is the inclusion of the full valence shell and invariance under spin-flip. For second period elements, this includes p-orbitals.